# Existence of solution of a 3-dimensional linear PDE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, partial-derivative

Maybe this is a canonical result but I'm facing difficulties to find a reference.

It is well known the following theorem about Linear Partial Differential Equations:

> **Theorem:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set and $\Gamma \subset \Omega$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve. Let $\gamma (s) = (\alpha(s),\beta(s))$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ parametrization of $\Gamma$, defined in the interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $a,b,c$ $\in$ $\mathcal{C}^1 (\Omega , \mathbb{R})$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^1 (I,\mathbb{R})$, such that $a$ and $b$ never simultaneously vanish in $\Omega$ and satisfy
>   $$\text{det} \begin{bmatrix}
> \alpha'(s) & a(\alpha(s),\beta(s)) \\
> \beta'(s) & b (\alpha(s),\beta(s)) 
> \end{bmatrix} \neq 0, \ \forall \  s \in I.  $$
>   Then, there is a solution of the Cauchy Problem
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> a(x,y)u_x + b(x,y) u_y = c(x,y),\quad &\text{if}\ (x,y) \in \Omega, \\
> u(\alpha(s),\beta(s)) = f(s)\ &\text{if} \ s \in I.  
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align*}
>   defined in a neighborhood of $\Gamma$.

However, I wasn't able to find a 3-dimensional version of this theorem. 
 All the books in which I looked for such a theorem only presented the 2-dimensional version. I think that a 3-dimensional version of this theorem would look like the following

> **Possible Theorem:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be an open set and $\Sigma \subset \Omega$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ surface. Let $\sigma (u,v) = (\sigma_1(u,v),\sigma_2(u,v),\sigma_3(u,v))$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ parametrization of $\Sigma$, defined in the square $I\times I \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that $a,b,c,d$ $\in$ $\mathcal{C}^1 (\Omega , \mathbb{R})$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^1 (I,\mathbb{R})$, such that $a$, $b$ and $c$ never simultaneously vanish in $\Omega$ and satisfy
>   $$\text{det} \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial u}(u,v) & \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial v}(u,v) & a(\sigma(u,v))\\
> \frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial u}(u,v) & \frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial v}(u,v) &b(\sigma(u,v))\\
> \frac{\partial \sigma_3}{\partial u}(u,v) & \frac{\partial \sigma_3}{\partial v}(u,v) & c(\sigma(u,v))
> \end{bmatrix} \neq 0, \ \forall \  (u,v) \in I\times I.  $$
>   Then, there is a solution of the Cauchy Problem
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> a(x,y,z)u_x + b(x,y,z) u_y + c(x,y,z)u_z = d(x,y,z) ,\quad& \text{if}\ (x,y,z) \in \Omega, \\
> u(\sigma(u,v) ) = f(u,v)\ &\text{if} \ (u,v) \in I\times I. \\
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align*}
>   defined in a neighborhood of $\Sigma$.

Does anyone know if this theorem is true and could indicate me a reference?